# How to make angular material expansion panel only open programatically and not when the panel header is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an mat-expansion-panel, which opens when the mat-expansion-panel-header is clicked. Is there a way to disable this behavior? I want to open the expansion panel elsewhere using its open method, and disable the ability to open it by clicking the header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbrvja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

This is not something that is supported natively.
Though you can quickly build a work-around in a few steps:

First you need to remove the indicator since it is not something the user will be able to interact with:

```
<mat-expansion-panel #panel1 [hideToggle]="true">
```

Note that I also gave the component a name in order to get its reference later on.

To prevent user interactions we will add a css class `prevent-click`:

`<mat-accordion class="prevent-click">`

```
.prevent-click{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you want the user to be able to interact with the content of the panels:

`<button class="authorize-click" mat-raised-button>test</button>`

```
.authorize-click{
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

NB: You can wrap the content of the expansion panel with this class to allow any interaction within.

---

To interact with the panels you use the reference of the panels (see above).
You can call 3 functions

- `open()`
- `close()`
- `toggle()`

`<button (click)="panel1.toggle()">Toggle panel 1</button>`

---

If you want to interact with the panels from your component, you need to get their references using `ViewChild()`.

Example:

`@ViewChild('panel1') firstPanel: MatExpansionPanel;`

```
public toggleFirstPanel(){
  this.firstPanel.toggle();
}
```

Comment: How to prevent just first click on accordion header. The thing is i have input in my `mat-panel-title` so on page load it get focus and when i write something its close then panel i want that behavior but not for the first time.

Comment: @Awais Did you find solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Ruthi Nope... I have changed my design to avoid this behavior